# Populating the write args with wagmi usePrepareContractWrite

Tags: react, wagmi

I am using wagmi `usePrepareContractWrite`and `write` to write to my contract. I am allowing the user to upload fields and create an NFT. Is there a way to set the args in the write function? For example i have

```
  const { config, status } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    addressOrName: "0xADDRESS",
    contractInterface:  "abi file",
    functionName: "safeMint",
  });
  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, write } = useContractWrite(config);


  write();
```

It works fine if i add the `args:["address", "NFT data"]` in the `usePrepareContractWrite` . However is there a way to set this in `write()` instead? As the NFT information is only available later after the user uploads and image and fields.

Docs: https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useContractWrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useState for something this like this, just throwing code together didnt test....

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "param"
  const [param, setParam] = useState("");

  const { config, status } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    addressOrName: "0xADDRESS",
    contractInterface:  "abi file",
    functionName: "safeMint",
    args: [param]
  });
  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, write } = useContractWrite(config);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
       <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="parameter type here"
          name="param"
          onChange={(e) => setParam(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button onClick={() => write()}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html